# What is the difference between a vortex ring and a circular line vortex?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

Can someone explain the difference between a vortex ring and a circular line vortex? Or are they the same?

Answer (score 3):

A vortex ring has a finite core radius $a$. The circular line vortex is a vortex ring with an infinitesimal core radius $a\to 0$. It is unphysical and only occurs in an inviscid fluid.

Comment: Sounds plausible. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: So is there a distinction between the core radius and the vortex ring radius?

Comment: @mdornfe1 See [this thesis](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/lab/people/sd/papers/Theses/NastjaBethke2008.pdf). In particular, Figure 1.3 and also section 4.2.